# Daisy chain two dell UltraSharp u2414h to MacBook Air (mid 2012)?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, thunderbolt, displayport

I have a MacBook Air (Mid 2012) and was thinking about buying 2 Dell UltraSharp u2414h monitors. Would it support daisy chaining these two monitors with the mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable connected from the MacBook to the monitor, and the other mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable connected from the monitor to the second monitor?

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169945/daisy-chain-of-two-dell-u2414h-to-macbook-pro-retina-13

Answer (score 1):

DisplayPort protocol doesn't chain. It is a one to one technology, so you need two ports on the Mac.

Thunderbolt does chain, so you could have one Thunderbolt Display and then plug a second monitor (either Thunderbolt or Mini DisplayPort) into the first monitor's second connector.

That works very well.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/272860 You might want to verify the edit on this answer by an anonymous which I think is a reply, thus rejected.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wont. You must have at least a Thunderbolt 2 connector. Unfortunately Yosemite doesnt support daisy chaining.

Comment: Of course thunderbolt chaining is supported. Can you source or clarify your answer? The limitation here is non-thunderbolt displays that don't chain, no? It has nothing to do with Yosemite.